# How to make string replacements case-insensitive

Tags: r, regex, replace, case-insensitive

I'm working on speech transcriptions with phonologically reduced forms:

```
reduced <- c("in n it", "du n no", "dun n it", "wan na", "gon na", "got ta")
```

I need to replace these forms with contiguous strings of the same letters but without the whitespaces:

```
reduced_replacements <- setNames(c("innit", "dunno", "dunnit", "wanna", "gonna", "gotta"),            # new forms
                                 c("in n it", "du n no", "dun n it", "wan na", "gon na", "got ta"))   # old forms
```

The problem is that the `reduced` forms may vary in terms of case. That is, the replacement needs to be case-insensitive. I've tried to make the regex pattern case-insensitive by including `(?i)`:

```
# pattern:
reduced_pattern <- paste0("(?i)\\b(", paste0(reduced, collapse = "|"), ")\\b")
```

But apparently that does not do the trick:

```
# test:
 tst <- c("Wan na go ? well du n no. come on", "i do n't know really",
          "will be great in n it, ", "it matters Dun n it",
          "Looks awesome. Dun n it?", "Gon na be terrific!")
 library(stringr)
 ifelse(grepl(reduced_pattern, tst, perl = T),
        str_replace_all(tst[grepl(reduced_pattern, tst)], reduced_replacements),
        tst)
[1] "Wan na go ? well dunno. come on" "i do n't know really"            "it matters Dun n it"            
[4] "Looks awesome. Dun n it?"        "Gon na be terrific!"             "Wan na go ? well dunno. come on"
```

None of the capitalized `reduced` forms get replaced. How can that be achieved in an effective way, i.e., other than by enumerating the upper-case forms in `reduced`and `reduced_replacements` and converting everything `tolower` case?

The **correct result** would be:

```
[1] "Wanna go ? well dunno. come on" "i do n't know really"            "it matters Dunnit"            
[4] "Looks awesome. Dunnit?"        "Gonna be terrific!"             "Wanna go ? well dunno. come on"
```

Comment: You do not need `ifelse` here, I believe, because replace operation leaves the string as is if no match is found.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a `stringr::str_replace_all` with a function as a replacement argument, where you can simply remove all whitespaces you want.

See an [R demo](https://tio.run/##XZBBa8MwDIXv/RVvusxmWdl5bOQy2GX3XQLFSdxg6trBVkgL@@@Z0mYNq05C0vskvTRN3tXJpLPKnFzokt5wZrw9o1H0bQKCQRdRYrTeox0glbhFE48WMVABcmgjwiPjEOKIZI33Zyo2uAWNTqS1RSdNhhMCHItyFjOOhtmmjI/h2viv/YrxkGFGm2Xj9jZUzuLPeDlPyAJIbu@aB9KbZNuhse3ygvuDgpbjr@laHi9PzlkX14zBZoXt@suRYYb2JrN9UaRKp6uqVuWrKJbiMl6IP96bPlu8g35IC3KeFaC4vEu296axO3FKidkF7rYU2A@hYReDOmncK04Cq6r8RAWR1tP0Cw):

```
library(stringr)
tst <- c("Wan na go ? well du n no. come on", "i do n't know really",
          "will be great in n it, ", "it matters Dun n it",
          "Looks awesome. Dun n it?", "Gon na be terrific!")
reduced <- c("in n it", "du n no", "dun n it", "wan na", "gon na", "got ta")
reduced_pattern <- paste0("(?i)\\b(?:", paste0(reduced, collapse = "|"), ")\\b")
str_replace_all(tst, reduced_pattern, function(x) str_replace_all(x, "\\s+",""))
## => [1] "Wanna go ? well dunno. come on" "i do n't know really"          
##    [3] "will be great innit, "          "it matters Dunnit"             
##    [5] "Looks awesome. Dunnit?"         "Gonna be terrific!"
```

Answer (score 0):

You could either make the case of `tst` and `reduced_replacements` same by using `tolower` and use `ignore_case = TRUE` in `regex`.

```
library(stringr)
str_replace_all(tst, regex(reduced_replacements, ignore_case = TRUE))

#[1] "wanna go ? well dunno. come on" "i do n't know really"           "will be great innit, "         
#[4] "it matters dunnit"              "Looks awesome. dunnit?"         "gonna be terrific!"
```

Comment: I want to keep upper-case and lower-case

Comment: In `reduced_replacements` everything is lower case, replacements cannot be case-insensitive, only pattern can be.